# Gathering my own rainwater to tovel

Tags: halacha, water, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Is it permissible to tovel dishes in a bucket which I've left outside to gather rainwater?

Is there an issue, for instance, if there hasn't been rain for a period of time?

Comment: Hello Benjamin, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Keep in mind that you should treat everything you read here [as if it came from a crowd of your friends](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. I hope to see you around the site!

Answer (score 4):

In order for a mikvah to be kosher, it must hold a minimum of 40 se'ah.  That's a little under 200 gallons, so a bucket of water wouldn't do it (unless it's a very large bucket).

Comment: http://www.indiamart.com/anydustbin-gurgaon/wheelie-bins.html "dustbin on wheels" has a 290 gallon garbage bin

Comment: It's more like 76-87 gallons and everyone's standard issue garbage can will do the trick so -1 (For completeness's sake, this answer is poor as the asker didn't specify why he wanted to tovel the dishes and a collection of rainwater less than 40 seah is kosher to tovel dishes for tumah reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

part 1 no can't dip in a bucket

[shulchan aruch yora daiya 201.6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5566)

can't dip in a KLI (vessel made to hold water)

[shulchan aruch yora daiya 201.7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5566)

Their is a way to stop something from being a vessel (make a hole that (if the kli was tomai it will) (taz (9) and shach 23 the size that an olive will fit though the hole) become tohor on bottom and cement it do the ground for it to be considered a building and not a kli)

part 2 [sulchan aruch yora daiya 201.41](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5576) if put out a bucket by a gutter to collect rain water when the clouds were colected for raining and they did not seperate befor it started to rain the water in it are considered seuvim (gathered waters): not natural (from heaven) but from people and they pasul the mikva with 3 lugim when put in a mikva before it is 40 soa
and if was put their before the clouds came and rained, then the water in it, is not seuvim so to use it for a mikva you need to brake the bucket or tilt it (but if you raise it it becomes sheuvim)

Comment: i answered before @Shmuel Brin

Comment: About the need to cite sources, see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/answers-when-is-a-source-required and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/712/better-to-post-an-answer-with-no-source-or-not-to-post-at-all. (*not always necessary, but always improves an answer*)